# Left aligning equations in gather environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, gather

I'm a newbie in LATEX.
I like to eliminate any extra typing for syntax, partly because I'm not accustomed to LATEX syntax and partly because I'm lazy.

I know that my way is not a recommended way, but I prefer to write all the equations between ONE `\begin{gather}` and `\end{gather}`,
so I don't need any `&` sign, `$` sign, `\begin{align}`, etc. (And I don't like center-aligning. In this way I have to write space in text using `\` instead of `' '`, but usually most of the things I write is just equations, so that doesn't matter much.)
so my code is like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}


\newcommand{\nl}{\\[10pt]}
\begin{document}
\large\textbf{Advanced Plasma Physics}
\\Homework2 \hfill heptacle
\section*{1.}
\begin{gather}
(1)\ \phi=-\frac{z}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}\frac{e^{-t^2}}{t-z}dt\\
\phi'=\frac{\phi}{z}-\frac{z}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}\frac{e^{-t^2}}{(t-z)^2}dt\\
=\frac{\phi}{z}+\frac{2z}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}\frac{te^{-t^2}}{t-z}dt\ (integration\ by\ part)\\
=\frac{\phi}{z}+\frac{2z}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}(1+\frac{z}{t-z})e^{-t^2}dt\\
=\frac{\phi}{z}+2z-2z\phi\\
=\frac{\phi}{z}+2z(1-\phi)\\
\therefore\ \phi'=(\frac{1}{z}-2z)\phi+2z\\
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

But the problem is that I wanna align equations on the equal sign so they would be more clear. But I coulnd't find any way for alinging in special position on gather environment. & sign doesn't work.
Or is there a way to left align all the equations in the align environment without & sign?

Comment: gather is specifically for non-aligned equations so asking to align in gather can ot work, making `=` auto-align would be theoretically possible but many "equations" are not `=` they may be inequalities or just long expressions that need to be split so using a single `&` to mark the alignment point is far more robust

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Your example didn't compile as it was, there was a blank line inside your `gather` environment. Also, each piece of coding, even inline should be enclosed between single quotation marks. As for your problem, I can't see any solution without using any `align` environment of its likes.

Comment: @FranckPastor Thank you for correcting my code. That is another annoying problem for my way, that my code should not include any blank line. OK maybe I should switch to align environment. This may sound as a too basic question, but I'm not quite sure how to left align eqn.s in align environment. fleqn alone doesn't work. Where should I plug in & signs?  (forgetting about aligning on equal sign for a while)

Comment: To left-align equations in an `align` environment, simply put the ampersand symbol at the very beginning of each equation.

Comment: Do you want to left align equation w.r.t. each other, or left align them at the left margin?

Comment: shouldn't `\large\textbf{Advanced Plasma Physics}` be a heading such as `\section{Advanced Plasma Physics}` ?  Using `\large` in that way makes the text in the entire document large.

Comment: @Bernard Usually I want to them to be aligned at the left margin, but in cases like this, if I'm just expanding equations, I want them to be aligned at certain equal sign. (and the first eqn. is aligned at the left margin)

Comment: @Septacle: What's the (1) in the beginning of the first line? The equation are already individually numbered on the right.

Comment: @Bernard That was the problem number. I copied only the first part of my code.

Comment: But do you want each  line to be numbered? On the left or on the right side?

Comment: @Bernard Actually numbered eqn.s are not what I intended. I don't need each line to be numbered. Well I might need some of them to be numbered in the future, but presently my focus is on alignment only.

Answer (score 1):

I propose you this layout:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphicx}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[margin=.5in, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\begin{center}\Large\bfseries}
\posttitle{\end{center}\vspace{2ex}}
\title{Advanced Plasma Physics}
\preauthor{\noindent\large Homework2\hfill}
\postauthor{}
\author{heptacle}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section*{1.}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\phi & =-\frac{z}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}\frac{e^{-t^2}}{t-z}\,dt\\
 \phi ' & =\frac{\phi}{z}-\frac{z}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}\!\frac{e^{-t^2}}{(t-z)^2}\,dt\\
 & =\frac{\phi}{z}+\frac{2z}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}\frac{te^{-t^2}}{t-z}\,dt & \quad & \text{\footnotesize(integration\ by\ parts)}\\
 & =\frac{\phi}{z}+\frac{2z}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}\Bigl(1+\frac{z}{t-z}\Bigr)e^{-t^2} dt\\
 & =\frac{\phi}{z}+2z-2z\phi\\
 & =\frac{\phi}{z}+2z(1-\phi) \\
  &\boldsymbol{\therefore} & \phi' &=\Bigl(\frac{1}{z}-2z\Bigr)\phi+2z
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain the last line, &\boldsymbol{\therefore} & \phi' &=\Bigl(\frac{1}{z}-2z\Bigr)\phi+2z , please? I'm not sure what each & means.

Comment: @Septacle. Oh! yes, naturally. An aligned environment, with several alignment points,  is organised in `columns`. Inside each column, the alignment point is specified by a `&`, and each column (except the first, which doesn't need it) is introcuced by another `&`. So `n`alignment points requires `2n – 1 &`.  So the `theredore` (in its bod version) is aligned with the `=` signs, and in the final formula $\phi'=.\cdots$ (which is is in the 2nd column), the `=` i aligned with the beginning of the comment 4 lines above, so  that it looks approximately centred and is more visible as a conclusion.